# Script to generate Joomla pages

Tags: python, mysql, joomla

I'm attempting to transfer a standard html webpage to the Joomla! CMS.  I'll be using Scrapy, a Python web crawler to grab and parse the old webpage.  Is there some way (preferably in Python) that I can write a script to convert 3000+ pages into Joomla's mySQL database?  Keeping the old style/css is not a priority.

Bonus points for an answer that can do this while maintaining the old URLs.

I am looking for some way to do this.  See my comment below for more information.  A useful answer will look like "This isn't possible" or "This is possible, but you need to use X [where X is a language, tool or other helper]"

Comment: We won't write your code for you. Show us what you have <- like I haven't said that a million times

Comment: This isn't getting you to write code for me.  I don't know if this is possible, and I'm looking for help in the right direction.  Googling things like "Joomla script" and "load html into Joomla" give me misinformation (outdated) or stuff that's not related to what I'm trying to do.  The closest I've come to what I want to do is a wiki tutorial on how to do it manually.  I hope it's obvious that I won't add 3000+ pages manually.

Comment: Yes it's possible - Joomla articles are just records in the `_content` table. How you scrape your pages, what bits you keep, and what you `INSERT INTO` your content table is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess my comment is an answer too.

Yes it's possible - Joomla articles are just records in the _content table. How you scrape your pages, what bits you keep, and what you INSERT INTO your content table is entirely up to you.

```
INSERT INTO jos_content 
(`title`, `alias`, `title_alias`, `intro_text`) VALUES
('Title', 'title', 'Title', 'Hello!' );
```

There will be other fields that need to be populated depending on your situation, such as category, but create an article manually using the back-end and see what the records look like.

Comment: I take it joomla doesn't have a nice 'add_content()' api which will handle categories, etc. for you. Inserting directly into a large and complicated database is almost always The Wrong Way to do this.

Comment: Generally I agree, but for content there is just the one table. Users are trickier, as there are security tables to think about. I'm sure there are data import/export plugins, and probably something like a SOAP API available. Alternatively, work from within the system, as a custom component.